# How to get the absolute path of a file (from workspace) in Jenkins pipeline script (in windows environment)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, filepath, absolute-path

**How to get the absolute path of a file (from workspace) in Jenkins pipeline script (in windows environment)**

**File locations** (The files are checked-out from Git and Jenkinsfile2.nprd will have the groovy pipeline script):

C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/dev-my-api/my-data-api/my-data-api/pom.xml
C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/dev-my-api/my-data-api/Jenkinsfile2.nprd

**Script:**

```
 stages {
        stage('Setup')  {
            steps {
                script {
                  pomPath = findFiles(glob: "**/pom.xml")[0].path
                  env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
                  pomDir = bat(script: "for %%F in ($pomPath) do set dirname=%%~dpF", returnStdout: true).trim()
                  echo "env.WORKSPACE:" + env.WORKSPACE
                  echo "pom file path:" + pomPath
                  echo "pom directory****:" + pomDir
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
env.WORKSPACE:C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dev-my-api
pom file path:my-data-api\pom.xml
pom directory****:C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\my-data-api>for %F in (my-data-api\pom.xml) do set dirname=%~dpF
```

**Requried path:**

C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/dev-my-api/my-data-api

How to get the above required path in Jenkins pipeline script without hard coding?

Answer (score 0):

```
pomPath = findFiles(glob: "**/$pomFile")[0].path
env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
def projectName = new File(pomPath).parent
baseDir = "${env.WORKSPACE}/$projectName"
```

I am able to get the required path. But looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following (find pom.xml relative path & get the full path)

```
 def pomPath = findFiles(glob: "**/pom.xml")[0].path
 echo new File(env.WORKSPACE, pomPath).getParent() +"\pom.xml"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that require script approvals? `new File()` and `File.getParent()` both? `pomPath` will be a [`FileWrapper`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.java) instance.

Comment: beware of using File object.  The CPS groovy executes some portions on master which won't have the file on it if you run on a node.  It can be useful for constructing and decomposing paths but beyond that it can yield failures